# Searching for keywords in two MySQL columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a user table with columns named *first_name* and *last_name*.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM users 
WHERE first_name LIKE '%keywords%' 
    OR last_name LIKE '%keywords%'
```

Using the above, if I search for "John" or for "Doe" I'll get a hit.

But if I search for "John Doe" I will get 0 results. How can I search MySQL in a way that will match "first_name last_name" rather than just one or the other?

Comment: Are you limited to only using one variable?

Comment: The variable is input from a search field, so it may be just one word or it may be two (first and last name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to split the keywords in your application, and then build the query as follows:

```
-- Split "John Doe" -> "John", "Doe"

SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(
    (
         first_name LIKE '%keyword_1%' OR
         last_name LIKE '%keyword_1%'
    )
    AND
    (
         first_name LIKE '%keyword_2%' OR
         last_name LIKE '%keyword_2%'
    )
)
```

The above would also match "Doe Joe", not just "Joe Doe". This will get bigger if you are searching into more columns, as you will have to add an "AND block" for each keyword.

In addition, this comes with a big performance cost, since such a query is unable to use indexes on `first_name` and `last_name`, if there are any. A better approach would be to use [Full Text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%keywords%';
```

Comment: Good, but won't be able to use an index if one exists for `first_name` or `last_name` columns, in addition to using `LIKE` with a wildcard on the lefthand side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [full-text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: Ehm - why do you provide the exact same link @Daniel Vassallo posted maybe 4 cm above your answer (if you sort by oldest, a bit further down if you sort by newest) six days before?

Comment: I think I must have missed that, after @Daniel Vassallo started off his answer in a quite different way.